# weasyprint renders PDF files with incomplete texts

Tags: python, pdf, debian, virtualenv, weasyprint

I'm using the weasyprint library in python for rendering PDF leaflets for various estate advertisments. However, some of the texts in the rendered files are missing parts of whole sentences.

The texts are in Czech language. For example, input text: "Zrekonstruovaný a jižně orientovaný byt ve 3. nadzemním podlaží bytového domu s výtahem."

Rendered text in PDF: "Zrekonstruovaný, jižněvýtahem.". So, it's missing the middle of the sentence.

After removing the special characters (ěščřžýáíé), this particular sentence is rendered ok, but this is not an universal rule, since other text can be render ok even with these characters.

I was not able to find any rule by which this happens. Also, this is happening only on our production server running on Debian. Rendering on my local Kubuntu runs just fine.

Tested with weasyprint v 0.31 and 0.33 running in virtual environment where only weasyprint and its dependencies are installed.

I'd be glad for any tips, thanks.

Comment: Its probably differences in the C library versions between Kubuntu and Debian is the culprit. Specifically pango, cairo and the various font and X libraries it uses.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to install `LibreOffice` on your server, it can run without a GUI and it is very good on converting documents to pdf. You could install the minimal version and see if it works -- if it doesn't work with the minimal installation, then you could install some additional recommended packages or even the full version. The following command would install the minimal version:

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends install libreoffice
```

If you have LibreOffice installed, then you could create the PDF with this command:

```
libreoffice --invisible --convert-to pdf /folder/document.docx --outdir /destination/folder/
```

I hope that helps!